# How do I search mapbox geocoder via poi categories?(fuel/gas stations/restaurant)

Tags: android, mapbox, geocoding, mapbox-android

I been adding mapbox to my app and I got the geocoder to search using auto complete.  I can't figure how to search categories tho.  Is that feature not yet available?  The API documents show it as "preview" and I also found this link.  https://github.com/mapbox/MapboxGeocoder.swift/issues/119

This what I'm trying to do

```
 // The geocoder client
 MapboxGeocoder client = new MapboxGeocoder.Builder()
 .setAccessToken(Constants.MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN)
 .setLocation("restaurant")
 .setType(GeocoderCriteria.TYPE_POI)
  .build();

 Response<GeocoderResponse> response;
  try {
 response = client.execute();
 } catch (IOException e)      {
 e.printStackTrace();
  return results;
 }

 features = response.body().getFeatures();
 results.values = features;
 results.count = features.size();
 return results;
}

@Override
 protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
 if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
 features = (List<GeocoderFeature>) results.values;
 notifyDataSetChanged();
 } else {
 notifyDataSetInvalidated();
 }
}
```

I switched it to this

```
MapboxGeocoding client = new MapboxGeocoding.Builder()
            .setAccessToken("pk.eyJ1IjoiamViMTkyMDA0IiwiYSI6ImNpbWNyODZyaDAwMmZ1MWx2dHdzcHQ5M2EifQ.IZsMnB3wOYFIaX1A5sy7Mw")
            .setLocation("restaurant")
            .setCountry("us")
            .setGeocodingType(GeocodingCriteria.TYPE_POI_LANDMARK)

            .setProximity(position)

            .build();

        Response<GeocodingResponse> response;
        try {
            response = client.executeCall();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return results;
        }

        features = (List<CarmenFeature>) response.body().getFeatures();
        results.values = features;
        results.count = features.size();
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
            features = (List<CarmenFeature>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
```

This gives me restaurants but not the ones in my proximity.
But if I change this

```
 .setLocation("restaurant")
```

To this

```
.setLocation(constraint.toString())
```

I can use the auto complete to search for the restaurant by name and I'll find whichever restaurant I'm looking for.

```
    final GeocoderAdapter adapter = new GeocoderAdapter(this);
    autocomplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.query);
    autocomplete.setLines(1);
    autocomplete.setAdapter(adapter);
    autocomplete.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                CarmenFeature result = adapter.getItem(position);
                autocomplete.setText(result.getText());
                updateMap(result.asPosition().getLatitude(), result.asPosition().getLongitude(), result.getProperties().toString());
            }
        });

    // Add clear button to autocomplete
    final Drawable imgClearButton = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.zoom_out);
    autocomplete.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, imgClearButton, null);
    autocomplete.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                AutoCompleteTextView et = (AutoCompleteTextView) v;
                if (et.getCompoundDrawables()[2] == null)
                    return false;
                if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                    return false;
                if (event.getX() > et.getWidth() - et.getPaddingRight() - imgClearButton.getIntrinsicWidth()) {
                    autocomplete.setText("");
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
 private void updateMap(double latitude, double longitude, String title) {
    // Marker
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                      .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                      .title(title));
    // Animate map
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
        .zoom(13)
        .build();
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), 5000, null);
}
```

Using this I set the title of the marker to show properties of the selected restaurant and so I could check the category it fall under to make sure I'm searching the right category when trying to search for "restaurant".

Do I need to set multiple categories if it fall under multiple categories?  How do I do that if I need to do that?

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me out with getting this to work?

Comment: Did you try to pass https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#point-of-interest-category-coverage as query text?